# Appending DDL on document ready doesn't let it have CSS on list items and not making them sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am using this code,

ASP.NET Control rendered html,

```
<ul id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_blSelectedFruits" class="fruitpurchaselist ui-sortable">
    <option data-id="18967" data-cid="18967;83" class="mybackground templi">Foggy-Mango</option>
    <option data-id="18982" data-cid="18982;83" class="mybackground templi">Rainy-Apple</option>
</ul>
```

JS Code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PopulateFruitDropDownList();

    $(".fruitpurchaselist").sortable({
        connectWith: ".fruitpurchaselist",
        cursor: "default",
        update: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () { FruitsChanged(); }, 100);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});

function PopulateFruitDropDownList() {
    var qsID = getParameterByName('id');
    var root = "_vti_bin/FruitFactory/FruitFactory.svc/";
    var url = root + "GetByID/";
    $.getJSON(url, {
        ID: qsID
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        var rFruits = data.GetByIDResult.Fruits;

        $.each(rFruits, function (index, item) {
                $("[id$=blSelectedFruits]")
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(item.Title)
                    .attr("data-id", item.ID)
                    .attr("data-cid", item.ID + ";" + item.CrateID)
                    .attr("class", "mybackground templi"));
            });
    });
}

function FruitsChanged() {
    var selectedFruitIDs = "";
    $("[id$=blSelectedFruits] li").each(function (index) {
        selectedFruitIDs += $(this).attr("data-id") + ";";
    });
    $("#hiddenSelectedFruits").val(selectedFruitIDs);
}
```

Issues,

1) I am not getting sort-able on my drop down list, before I used to add list items from code behind and it worked but now I am adding them from web services (rest) it stopped working.

2) In CSS I have a class like this,

```
.fruitpurchaselist li {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

It doesn't gets applied to dynamically added list items as well, so I need to add a temporary templi class to it...

Comment: Initialize `.sortable()` in the `.done()` function. You're making an ajax call but not waiting for it to complete before applying `sortable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's the issue but it seems your output HTML lacks list-items. From the code you provided here it looks like there are two `<option>` Elements.

So, when you are writing `.class li` in your CSS but there are no `<li>` Elements in your HTML, surely nothing will happen.

Comment: That was it, I was supposed to add list items not "options", thank you so much

Comment: Wonderful. Glad I was able to help. =)